# Count issue due to variable not operating properly, subtracting or adding wrong

Tags: python, count, modulo

This is the setup for a calendar, is there a better way to create a count?

```
for k,v in months.items():
    print(k) # print the month name
    print(month_header)
    while month_daycount > 7:
        month_daycount -= 7
    count = month_daycount
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your code specifically, but I feel that your code could be greatly simplified by using the datetime library of Python. You could then simply use the delta function to iterate over the days and as you already have the formatting defined, your problem would be solved!

Answer (score 0):

You are in *desperate need* of the modulo operator to get your columns lined up!

If you are not familiar, do a little google searching, but the essence is that the modulo operator returns the *remainder* when doing division and is commonly used for things that roll over, like converting a large number of hours into the time of day using modulo to remove the number of days.  In python the modulo operator is `%`.  For example, using a 24 hour clock, and a starting time of 15, if I want to add 100 hours and know what time it is I can:

```
(15 + 100) % 24
# 19
```

to see that the new time is 1900hrs (7pm), which is the remainder after dividing by 24.

You can use this to keep track of what column you are in, as long as you keep a running total of the items printed.  Here is a toy example you can incorporate in your code with some modification:

##### Code:

```
periods = [8,15,17,20]
row_length = 7

total_chars = 0
for period in periods:
    # find the current column using modulo to get the remainder
    current_column = total_chars % row_length
    # add n tabs to set first col
    print('\t' * current_column, end='')   
    for day_count in range(1, period+1):
        print(day_count, end='\t')
        total_chars += 1
        if total_chars % row_length == 0:  # use modulo again to see if we are at end of row, 0 remainder...
            print()
    print('\na new period has started!')
```

##### Output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
8   
a new period has started!
    1   2   3   4   5   6   
7   8   9   10  11  12  13  
14  15  
a new period has started!
        1   2   3   4   5   
6   7   8   9   10  11  12  
13  14  15  16  17  
a new period has started!
                    1   2   
3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  
17  18  19  20  
a new period has started!
```